# Bootstrap classes do not run in Laravel 8 views with auth module

Tags: css, laravel, bootstrap-4, laravel-8, laravel-jetstream

On the Laravel 8 project I've done the next commands:

```
composer require laravel/ui
php artisan ui bootstrap
npm install && npm run dev
```

And now I'm trying to add the new button with bootstrap classes to the dashboard page, generated by laravel/jetstream, but bootstrap styles were not applied. I've read, this package uses Tailwind UI, but I want to leave its style and to code whole project in Bootstrap.

Can you help me with how to say to Laravel mix to use Bootstrap files?

Thank you.

Comment: The command you've shown pulls in `laravel/ui`, however, you then mention `jetstream` these are 2 different packages. Which package have you installed?

Comment: I installed Livewire

Comment: I hope this may help https://www.techiediaries.com/laravel-8-bootstrap-4-tailwind/

Answer (score 4):

Yes. By default, Jetstream uses [Tailwind CSS](https://tailwindcss.com). But you are free to use other CSS frameworks as well. In your case all you have to do is install Bootstrap and include the CSS in your HTML. For example, you can include the Bootstrap CSS file from CDN your main application layout `.blade.php` file.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

I'm not sure if there would be class name conflicts with Tailwind CSS.